# Allow moderators to move messages without inviting users into the new room

Tags: feature-request, chat, moderator-tools

The tool to move multiple messages into a different chat room also invites all users that particpated into that new room. Which does make some sense if you want to continue the discussion there, but it is absolutely counterproductive if I'm moving messages because I want to get rid of the entire discussion and just put the whole mess somewhere where it doesn't draw any attention.

I think the move tool has some potential as a tool for moderating chat, but the automatic invitation of users makes it useless for this purpose and because I didn't think about this rather obscure feature I just invited a whole bunch of people to a discussion I wanted to archive quietly.

Please just make this invitation feature optional, and off by default. Though the ability to silently move should be restricted to moderators, and not be available to room owners.

Comment: You're a moderator... Just *mass delete* the messages.

Comment: @Shog9 See [my other feature request on why the mass deletion tool sucks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270761/change-the-way-mass-deletion-works-in-chat)

Comment: Seems like fixing the deletion tool is the better way to go then (although frankly I'm not as concerned about it as you are). Under normal circumstances, moving messages *shouldn't* be completely secret.

Comment: @Shog9 I was mostly trying to find a new way to just stop a discussion in chat and put it a bit out of sight instead of getting out the nuke. I'm not yet sure if it is a good idea, but I thought it's worth a try

Comment: BTW, you can totally mass-delete and *then* mass-migrate.

Comment: Moving messages *isn't* secret, there's a message posted that shows how many were moved and where they were moved to.

Comment: @KevinReid I changed the title to focus on the part that is different than the duplicate, as I'm focusing on moderators using this tool while the duplicate (and especially the answer by balpha) are about room owners.